# Laravel Import csv to database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and would like to know if there is any better way to import data as csv to database.Also i need to import data into multiple tables so if anyone can help me out it would be great time saver for me, any sample code is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very wake description, but this is a snip of how i do it:

```
    $fp = fopen($vendor->product_feed_url, 'r');
    $head = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ',', '"');
    while ($column = fgetcsv($fp, 1000, ',', '!')) {
            try {
                if (!(count($head)==count($column))){
                    continue;
                }
                $column = array_combine($head, $column);
```

in the $column, you should have one line from the csv document.